# Workbenches won't appear in Main Hall- Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

For the Heathfire extension you can build houses, and for each section of the house is a workbench to add in furnishings. None of them are appearing for me except the entry way, how can I fix it??

Comment: Did you already built other extensions? The first one is the hallway, but you have to built the other rooms from outside the building (the workbench outside) to be able to have them show up.

Comment: Once extensions are built, you can use the Drafting Table outside to Hide/Display the workbenches.  You may want to double check that you don't have them Hidden.